# intents and intents filter

Tags: android

How to send any message from one activity to anothere using intent and intent filters.

Comment: Have you heard of www.google.com and developer.android.com ?

Answer (score 2):

you use the [putExtras(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)) method of the Intent

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("my.unique.extras.key", "this is my message");
myIntent.putExtras(extras);
```

Then in the Intent you retrieve the extras

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if ( extras != null ) {
  if ( extras.containsKey("my.unique.extras.key") ) {
    this.setTitle(extras.getString("my.unique.extras.key"));
  }
}
```

this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165401/send-message-through-intent-filter/3165504).

Answer (score 0):

An **Intent** can contain data. This data can be used by the receiving component. There are two types of Intent

- **Explicit Intent**
- **Implicit Intent**

and to inform the system which implicit intents they can handle, activities, services, and broadcast receivers can have one or more **intent filters**.
There are three test under Intent-filter these are

- **Action test**
- **Category test**
- **Data test**

  class to send message from one activity to another using Intent and Intent-filter

  ```
     public class MessageActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.message);
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
     startActivity(i);
    }}
  ```

  xml code is

  ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  ```

Here we use Implicit Intent so we have to give permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MESSAGE" />
```

and register the Message class inside application

```
    <activity android:name=".MessageActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MESSAGE" />   </intent-filter> 

      </activity>
```