# Send message through intent filter

Tags: android

how to send a message from one activity to another using intent and intent filters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you use the [putExtras(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)) method of the Intent

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("my.unique.extras.key", "this is my message");
myIntent.putExtras(extras);
```

Then in the Intent you retrieve the extras

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if ( extras != null ) {
  if ( extras.containsKey("my.unique.extras.key") ) {
    this.setTitle(extras.getString("my.unique.extras.key"));
  }
}
```